# Facebook SDK post photo likes

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-like, photo

I try to post a photo like on behalf of the current user. But i get #200 Permission Error. What i am doing wrong? Need i other permissions? I tried also with all permissions, still no luck.

```
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

class photo_liker {
function __construct()
{
    $this->facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => fb_appID, 'secret' => fb_secret, 'fileUpload' => true, 'cookie' => true));
}

function postPhotoLike($photoid)
{
    try {
        $args = array('access_token' => $this->facebook->getAccessToken());
        $upload_photo = $this->facebook->api('/' . $photoid . '/likes', 'post', $args);
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }

}

function login()
{
    try {
        $uid = $this->facebook->getUser();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }

    if($uid) {
        try {
            $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e);
        }

        return true;
    } else {
        $login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,publish_stream'));

        ob_clean();
        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $login_url . "'</script>");
        exit ;
    }
    return false;
}

 }

$test = new photo_liker();
$test->login();
$test->postPhotoLike('10150758570710223');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was because the test users from Facebook dev had not liked the page on with the photo was posted. If they like the page all goes right.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer if it solves your original problem